# Python child class has no parent method

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I'm trying to call a method from the parent's class in the child class, but I get an exception.

That's the parent class:

```
from typing import Dict


class Parent:
    __arg: Dict

    @property
    def arg(self) -> Dict:
        return self.__arg
```

That's the child class:

```
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, title) -> None:
        super(Child, self).__init__()
        self.__arg: Dict = {
            "some": "text",
        }
```

When I'm trying to run `Child("Metallica").arg` I get this exception: `AttributeError: 'Child' object has no attribute '_Parent__arg'`

Can someone help me please :3

Comment: Why do you want to name the `Dict` in `Parent` `__arg`?

Comment: @quamrana Dict is from typing, sorry for not mentioning it xD

Comment: Yes, I realise that, but what about the name `__arg`? Why that name?

Comment: @quamrana to make it private

Comment: @more-suo **that does not make it private**. Python **doesn't have private variables**. this is *crucial* to understand. It does, however, have name-mangling, which serves the same purpose as a `private` access modifier for *one* particular use-case, it *prevents name collisions in the sublcass*. So if you *want* to use it in the subclass, then **dont use double-underscore name mangling**. Note, you would have the same problem if you use `private` in a class that actually had private variables

Comment: Soooo the solution is just to use a *single* underscore, which mean "internal part of the API touch at your own risk!". i.e. privacy by *convention*. Although, since you are just exposing this anyway, you might as well remove the `property` and just sue a regular attribute, `self.arg = {"some":"text"}`